# How do i set up Zend Server on Mac?

Tags: php, macos, installation, zend-server, zend-server-installation

I have a mac, and want to set up Zend Server. I am not a php developer but experimenting and when in stalled it and all, i can access the administration control etc, but when i try to add my own code to the rood documents folder, it says it can't find the site. Im not sure if it is the right place to put it, but its located in the same folder as the zend server symlink.

Are there any other tweaks I'm supposed to do? I just installed using the dog installer package that zend has for the mac.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: zend is pretty complex to start off if you'er not a php developer. I'd start with something like codeigniter.

Comment: Zend server !== Zend framework. You have to approach problems one at a time. At this point it seems you're having basic issues with Zend Server installation. Which are better suited on serverfault.com perhaps.

Comment: Zend Framework doesn't require Zend Server. I'd simply use Apache or Nginx, you'll get way better support for them online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is a screen cast to better understand the concept, so here is one:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=097GoCeZm2U

Comment: He's trying to set it up on a Mac, so a WAMP install guide video is probably the last thing he needs.